# Laravel|Inertia|Vue.js -Jetstream cannot authenticate with correct credentials when hosted in cPanel. Local env it does

Tags: vue.js, vite, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm experiencing a pecuilar thing with my Laravel|Inertia|Vue.js application.
I'm using Jetstream auth, I can get authenticated on local env, but hosting in cPanel, I cannot be authenticated, more worse I can't get any error--however prviosuly it was working fine until it just stopped. Kindly help

Comment: What does the error_log say from `metrics` -> `errors`?

Comment: There, no any logged logged error. 
https://ibb.co/K5nYMhY

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no screen errors.  Even at the console, and Network. 
It's a Vue app and backend Laravel using inertia to make requests. 
The strange is this: If i key in wrong credentials, i get a feedback of error validation, but if i key in correct credentials, it loads and quits without any feedback.

NB. This problem is not available in local env.